# Can we restrict some functionality in SQL Report Builder?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2014

We are providing user can change the existing reports columns or look and feel by SQL Report Builder in Web application.

I want to restrict some functionality of Report Builder like below:

1. User cannot able to use "Save As" functionality. (because we link report path in our db.)
2. In report toolbar, User can only can see Dataset fields only. User cannot change report parameters or Dataset fields or datasource connection etc.

Is it possible to restrict?

Thanks...!!!

Comment: As far as I know, no. If you want to delegate the ability to edit reports to users who you cannot trust with Report Builder, you should probably investigate using a different reporting tool, or building something yourself to sit within or on top of SSRS to allow the level of customisation you wish to permit.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and No.

Option 1 is the Browser Role, See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159864(v=sql.105).aspx

Option 2 is tricky as individual parts of the report can't be locked down (at least in 2008 r2 it can't)

Comment: For Option1,  View Reports can only see the reports as of my understanding. But what i want is User can Save the report but can not make new report with option "Save As". So that one possible?

Comment: There is no easy way to do this, Save and Save As are the same level of security.